# Microsoft Word is adding extra space between words as I type

Tags: microsoft-word

Word is adding space between words as I type. Here is the layout of my document:
[image]

It simply consists of two pages with the first page being vertically aligned at the center. In order to allow for a normal top alignment for the following pages, a section break was added. Look at this GIF for a visual of what is going on:

[image]

Notice how the spacing between the words change as I type. I tried removing the section break, but it did not work. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not an issue to fix :-)

You can align the text four ways:

1. align left -> all lines start at equal distance from the left marginal; distance to right marginal varies
2. align right -> all lines end at equal distance from the right marginal; distance to left marginal varies
3. align center -> the center of all lines stays at the center of the page; distance to both marginals varies
4. Justify -> distance to both marginals stays the same

And you've chosen justify. Because the words are not equal length, the way to justify a text is to adjust the space between the words - spacing on a single line is kept equal, tho. If the line contains too many characters it will start to get too tight, so Word will drop words to the line below.

To "fix" it you can choose to align right. If you want to keep the nice, justified look, you need to allow Word to adjust the spacing. Alternatively you can choose to hyphenate the text - that will make the spacing across lines more equal; but not exactly. Hyphenation will also make the other alignment options more justified.

Text alignment is chosen with the four buttons on the toolbar just above the word "Paragraph".

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/align-text-left-or-right-center-text-or-justify-text-on-a-page-70da744d-0f4d-472e-916d-1c42d94dc33f

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have never used justify alignment and didn't know what is was or that it was selected :\

Comment: You're welcome. I remember the first time I ever tried "justify". The result looked absolutely horrible - my mother tongue has a lot of conjunctive words and uses suffixes instead of prepositions... :-D